# Jasmine can't spy on event handler?

Tags: javascript, testing, event-handling, jasmine

Trying to test that an event handler gets called on a clicked element with Jasmine. Have a "Pad" object that contains a DOM element "PadElement", which gets clicked. The event handler is a method on the Pad object:

```
GRAPH.Pad = function(graphDiv, graph) {
    this.graph = graph;

    this.clickHandler = function(e) {
        console.log('padElement clickHandler called');
        //this.graph.createVertex(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    };
    this.padElement = GRAPH.padElement(graphDiv, this.clickHandler);
}

GRAPH.padElement = function(graphDiv, clickHandler) {
    //Initialize pad
    var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var pad=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    pad.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'pad');
    graphDiv.appendChild(pad);
    pad.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    return pad;
}
```

The Jasmine test:

```
var testDiv = document.createElement('div');
var testGraph = new GRAPH.Graph(testDiv);
var testPad = new GRAPH.Pad(testDiv, testGraph);

  it('has its clickHandler function called when its padElement is clicked',
    function() {
      spyOn(testPad, "clickHandler");
      simulateClick(testPad.padElement);
      //testPad.clickHandler();
      expect(testPad.clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

However, the test FAILS. Note that the event listener does get called (console.log writes successfully with a mouse click and with simulateClick), AND if I just call the testPad.clickHandler() directly Jasmine's spy can pick it up. But what happens during the actual test? Does the event handler invocation get transferred to a different object at runtime? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually testing that `GRAPH.padElement` calls the supplied `clickHandler` and not that `this.clickHandler` of `GRAPH.Pad` is called by `GRAPH.padElement`. How I would do that is

```
var testDiv = document.createElement('div');
var clickHandlerSpy = jasmine.CreateSpy();
var padelement = padElement(testDiv , clickHandlerSpy);

  it('has its clickHandler function called when its padElement is clicked',
    function() {
      simulateClick(testPad.padElement);
      expect(clickHandlerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This may sound little different to what you are trying to achieve. But in ideal unit testing world you should be testing each unit independently, so I would first test that `padElement` does what it's supposed to do (as above) and then write another test to make sure `GRAPH.Pad` is passing correct handler to `padElement`. Now to do that I would not create `padElement` directly from within `GRAPH.Pad` but somehow inject it from outside and then mock it in the jasmine specs. If you are not clear on this part let me know and I can put some code together for you.

Answer (score 3):

To add a more generic explanation:

**You need to spy before attaching the function as an event listener**.

Some pseudo-code:

```
it("succeeds", function(){
  var o = {}
  o.f = function() { console.log("event caught!");} //your eventHandler
  spyOn(o, "f").and.callThrough(); //o.f is now a spy
  addEventListener('click', o.f); //spy listens for event 

  fireEvent("click"); //"event caught!" is written to console

  expect(o.f).toHaveBeenCalled(); //success, we're happy
});



it("fails", function(){
  var o = {}
  o.f = function() { console.log("event caught!");} //your eventHandler
  addEventListener('click', o.f); //your eventHandler function listens for event
  spyOn(o, "f").and.callThrough(); //o.f is now a spy

  fireEvent("click"); //"event caught!" is written to console

  expect(o.f).toHaveBeenCalled(); //fail, we waste a couple of hours not understanding why
});
```

So if you know your handler is being called, but the spy does not register as `.tohaveBeenCalled()` check what happens first: your spy or the assignment of the listener. The spy needs to come first.